# SQL join Query in SQL management studio

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT dbo.Items.MaxStockLevel
    ,dbo.Items.MinStockLevel
    ,dbo.ItemsDefination.NAME
FROM dbo.Items
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemsDefination ON dbo.Items.BusinessUnitId = dbo.ItemsDefination.BusinessUnitId
    AND dbo.Items.ItemId = dbo.ItemsDefination.ItemId
```

I have a single column in one of the database tables - dbo.ItemDefination, the column name is dbo.ItemDefination.Name. This column contains three values that I need to extract separately from each other - product name, category, and subcategory.
001-00-0000 this Id represents Category, 001-01-0000 this Id represents Subcategory and 001-01-0001 this Id represents Product Name
Is this possible ?

Comment: It is possible, but this is very bad design. Your headaches are only going to increase going further with this format. For start, we need to see some sample data from this column. Note that the sample data has to cover all of the distinct possible scenarios of data delimitations from your column, in order to make sure we start off the right way.

Comment: are product name, category and subcategory delimited in some way? Like a comma or a tab? If those three values are somehow delimited, you could write your own Split function to separate them

Comment: 001-00-0000 this Id represents Category, 001-01-0000 this Id represents Subcategory and 001-01-0001 this Id represents Product Name.

Comment: in that case you just need to split the field on the dash using your own split function

Answer (score 1):

It might help you, if it is delimited by comma.

```
Declare @temp table(Name Varchar(100))

Insert into @temp
Select 'abc,ert,err'  union all
Select 'abc1,ert1,err1'  union all
Select 'abc2,ert2,err2'  union all
Select 'abc3,ert3,err3'  union all
Select 'abc4,ert4,err4'  


Select PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,',','.'),1) Produst, 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,',','.'),2) Category ,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,',','.'),3) SubCategory
from @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

On a second thought, you could use SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Name], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [Name])) As ProductName,
SUBSTRING(
SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) +1, LEN([Name])),
 0,
CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) +1, LEN([Name])))
) As ProdCat,
SUBSTRING(
SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) +1, LEN([Name])),
CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) +1, LEN([Name])))+1,
LEN([Name])-CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) +1, LEN([Name])))
) As ProdSubCat
FROM dbo.ItemsDefination
```